# QGIS 3.10 (and newer). Random points inside polygon (Variable) tool is missing?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Using the current long term release version of QGIS (v3.10), I see the 'Random Points Inside Polygons (variable)' tool is changed. It used to look like this.

The key field here is the 'number field'. Which allows you to select a column in the attribute table of that layer in order to generate a corresponding number of points based on the values of that field.

[image]

Now the tool is replaced by simply 'Random Points inside polygons' which looks like this:

[image]

The 'Number field' input box is missing.  What happened?  Has the old tool been renamed?

Comment: You will find advanced options by clicking the icon at the right side of "Point count or density".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just hit the rectangle with the two triangles attached to it to the right of the `point count or density` field. This allows you to choose `data defined override` - e.g. by choosing a column which holds valid values.

So no, there hasn't be any renaming, the GUI simply has been made more sleek.